# I want vertical aligned text from bottom to top. how to achieve it.? attaching the expected out

Tags: css

I want vertical aligned text from bottom to top. how to achieve it.? attaching the expected out.

HTML

```
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">Title from bottom to top</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.class1 {
background: #1ac6d3;
position: relative;
width: 40px;
height:200px;
}

.class2 {
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
left: 50%;
width: 200px;
}
```

Expected OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-orientation` and then rotate it `180deg`

```css
.class1 {
  background: #1ac6d3;
  width: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.class2 {
  text-orientation: sideways;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">Title from bottom to top</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-orientation` is doing nothing here. remove it and you will have the same result (it also have very poor support with the value `sideways`, only Firefox support this value)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this.

By position:-

```css
.class1 {
  background: #1ac6d3;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.class2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">Title from bottom to top</div>
</div>
```

By Display Flex:-

```css
.class1 {
  background: #1ac6d3;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.class2 {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">Title from bottom to top</div>
</div>
```

By Display Block:-

```css
.class1 {
    background: #1ac6d3;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
}

.class2 {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">Title from bottom to top</div>
</div>
```

You can also do this with Display Table Property

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
   .class2{
    font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #323232;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-200px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-200px);
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-200px); 
        -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
        -ms-transform-origin: top left;
         transform-origin: top left;
         background: #1ac6d3;
         padding: 8px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="class1">
      <div class="class2">Title from bottom to top</div>
    </div>
```